# How do I find out what's the error on the fields in Teiid Designer source model

Tags: model, teiid

I just created an Mongodb source model in Teiid Designer. After that, I got a tiny red cross symbol on the table defined in the model indicating error. When I expand the table, I saw the same error symbols on several fields. I double check and triple check, the data type on these fields match the data type in the physical data source. How can I find out what error it's indicating on these fields? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom panel in Teiid Designer, you will see a panel for error messages those should describe the reasons.

Comment: I finally found out what's needed. Somehow Teiid wants the native data types on those fields. Once I put them in, the error symbol is gone. Now here comes another problem on the VDB created out of the view. When I tested it, it gave me the following error

Comment: 15:55:25,813 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO2)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID50072 The username "user" and/or password and/or payload token could not be authenticated by security domain teiid-security.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.LogonException thrown from org.teiid.jboss.JBossSecurityHelper.authenticate(JBossSecurityHelper.java:152). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.

I have a user created with odata role to use for JDBC connection. JDBC test under Teiid instance returned OK.